# Php htmlspecialchars with php code inside then decode it without executing the code

Tags: php, html

What happens when the first line is executed? Is the code being executed? Because nothing appears in the browser..

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode("&lt;?php file_put_contents(&quot;./tete.php&quot;,&quot;der inhalt&quot;); ?&gt;");     ?>


(I did htmlspecialchar on String: "<?php file_put_contents("./tete.php","content"); ?>" before and then want to decode it and it shouldn't be executed and if possible displayed in browser.)
```

I am wondering because nothing appears in the browser and there is a echo.. But i don't think the code is being executed because otherwise their should be a new tete.php file now in the directory.. so what happens?

Comment: It just echos the string. If your browser isnt displaying anything, its probably interpreting it as an empty html tag. right click > view source to see the raw output

Comment: Damn yes it's right in the sourcecode.. My browser just couldn't interpret/dsiplay it correctly as text.. Thank! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the raw source code that is being output to the browser, it contains `<?php file_put_contents("./tete.php","content"); ?>`, which is being interpreted as an HTML tag and hence doesn't show up. And no, it's not being evaluated as PHP code. That would require that all strings are checked whether they're runnable PHP code and then get evaluated. And if the result of that is another string which is runnable PHP code? Infinite recursive PHP execution…? That's not how it works.

Comment: Ah thanks it appears in the sourcecode! My browser just can't interpret it.. Would be cool when it could just show it as text when it's to stupid to interpret a tag... Thank you and have a good day! :-)

Comment: It's not "too stupid", it merely acts on the rules of HTML.

Comment: Yes okay... :D Maybe you are right ;-) I thought: There is no such tag like php so it wil display it as text..^^ my fault